# glib-2.0: g_spawn_command_line_sync() - unknown stdout length

Tags: glib

`function g_spawn_command_line_sync()` has argument `"gchar **standard_output"`:

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-command-line-sync

I need read binary data from standard_output, but I not known length of standard_output.

```
Function g_spawn_command_line_sync():
```

http://fossies.org/dox/glib-2.38.2/gspawn-win32_8c_source.html#l01452

execute:

```
GString *outstr = NULL;
*standard_output = g_string_free (outstr, FALSE);
```

`Struct GString include "gsize len"`, but `g_spawn_command_line_sync()` accessible only `"gchar **"`.

I have next solution. I write `size of stdout` to `stderr`, which not using.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>

int main()
{
    gint exit_status = 0;
    gchar *p_stdout = NULL;
    gchar *p_stderr = NULL;
    GError *p_error = NULL;
    gboolean result;

    result = g_spawn_command_line_sync("./make_image.py", &p_stdout, &p_stderr, &exit_status, &p_error);

    if (!result) {
        if (p_error != NULL) {
            printf(p_error->message);
        }
        else {
            printf("ERROR: Command not run\n");
        }
    }
    else if (exit_status != 0) {
        printf(p_stderr);
    }
    else {
        int size = atoi(p_stderr);
        gchar *p_c = p_stdout;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            fputc(*p_c++, stdout);
        }

        //printf(p_stdout);
    }

    if (p_stdout) {
        g_free(p_stdout);
    }

    if (p_stderr) {
        g_free(p_stderr);
    }

    if (p_error) {
        g_error_free(p_error);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [g_spawn_async_with_pipes](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-async-with-pipes).  Reading binary data from file descriptors is easy.  If you really need to detect when the child exits, add a callback using [g_child_watch_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-child-watch-add) or [g_child_watch_add_full](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-child-watch-add-full), but you can probably get away with just reading the descriptor until it returns an error.